# IE9 HTML5 Video Bug?

Tags: html5-video

I have some weird bug happening only in IE9, whenever I want to play a HTML5  it won't load automatically, but if I click the address bar and press enter, it works, it's driving me crazy

```
<video id="video_1_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
              controls preload="auto" width="480" height="270"  
              poster="images/videos/video1_1_poster.png"  
              data-setup='{"controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": auto}'>  
                <source src="images/videos/vid1.1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
                <source src="images/videos/vid1.1.webm" type='video/webm' />
                <source src="images/videos/vid1.1.ogv" type='video/ogv' />
            </video>
```

Comment: Does it work in another browser? There are limitations as to what codecs IE9 supports as well, so you might need to transcode the video to something else for IE9 to like it

Comment: Yep, it works on every other browser, also the codec I'm using is H.264, created for IE 9 by the client, the weird thing here is that it  kinda works, after I open the site again :/

Answer (score 0):

See this page; it provides a solution to the poster issue with IE9, and expands on video codecs:

http://www.artbymikeshaffer.com/vids/finalproject_chetbakerquartet_poster7.html

Some simple CSS and conditional statements did the trick. I'm now of the opinion posters should be placed at the beginning (first frame) and end (last frame) of a video, as if they were album covers. In this way, an image at the beginning of the video will give the viewer SOME visual idea of why they should play it (just like the reason that sometimes you buy an album because of its cover).

Cheers